# Pipenv: dependencies of platform specific packages are installed unconditionally?

Tags: python, pipenv

I am trying to integrate `pipenv` into my new project because I need to have some dependencies for development only and I couldn't find an easy way to have additional dev dependencies with `pip` or `venv`.

However, I ran into an issue when trying it:

My project depends on `pypiwin32` when it's used in windows. Because it's a windows dependency, I installed it with the command:

`pipenv install "pypiwin32 ; platform_system == 'Windows'"`

which succesfully added this dependency to my `Pipfile` with the platform restriction:

```
# Pipfile

[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]
# dependencies...

[packages]
# dependencies...
pypiwin32 = {markers = "platform_system == 'Windows'",version = "*"}

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
```

The problem is that `pypiwin32` depends on the `pywin32` package and when I looked in the `Pipfile.lock` file I saw that it's not restricted to windows only:

```
# Pipfile.lock

"pypiwin32": {
    "index": "pypi",
    "markers": "platform_system == 'Windows'",
    "version": "==223"
},
"pywin32": {
    "version": "==224"
},
```

which is weird. I tested it by changing the restriction to 'Linux' and trying to install the dependencies into a new environment without the `Pipfile.lock` and it ignored `pypiwin32` as expected but it installed `pywin32` anyway despite the fact that it's not listed in the `Pipfile` and that it's a dependency of a package which was ignored.

This is a serious problem because if I decide to deploy or develop on a linux machine, it will simply not work because `pywin32` isn't available on linux or mac (as far as I know).

Is there a way to correctly mark the dependencies of a package with the restrictions of the package?

I don't want to manually edit `Pipfile.lock` (I also don't think it will work because when I tried to install it into a new environment, I copied the `Pipfile` only).

Alternatively, is there a better way to manage my dependencies? I need the ability to specify development dependencies that won't be installed on a production environment and I need the ability to specify platform specific dependencies. `pip` with the `requirements.txt` can't handle the first request as far as I know, which is why I tried switching to `pipenv`.

I tried looking it up with no success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are these [pep 508 annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/)? There's a bug on pipenv already about them [not propagating properly](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4003), that might be worth adding to

Answer (score 7):

Adding platform specific installation of both `pypiwin32` and `pywin32` packages explicitly in the pipfile should solve the issue.

```
pypiwin32 = {version = "*", sys_platform = "== 'win32'"}
pywin32 = {version = "*", sys_platform = "== 'win32'"}
```

The prerequisite package `pywin32` will in that case also be ignored on linux.